# How do you open a file in mit-scheme edwin?

Tags: scheme

I have a file "file.scm"

```
(define (foo ...) ...)
(define (bar ...) ...)
(define (baz ...) ...)
```

If I use `(load "file.scm")` it returns `Value :baz`

Since it evaluated baz the function is available to be used, but foo and bar were not evaluated and cannot be used.

What modifications would need to be made to file.scm so that it returns:

```
Value: foo
Value: bar
Value: baz
```

when I type `(load "file.scm")` into the REPL?

Comment: Dos you try to use them? what error did you get? "load" will only print the last return value.

Comment: I don't use them in "file.scm". I want to be able to load in a file of definitions and use them in the interpreter.

Comment: Maybe a better question would be, What is the appropriate way to make multifile programs in scheme?

Comment: You do that with the load function. As I said before, It only prints the last value, but it evaluates the entire file. You could set load-noisly? to #t to see every expression evaluated. (https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-user/Loading-Files.html#Loading-Files)[load]